# CSS Resizing screen causes footer to be displayed wrongly

Tags: html, css, footer

I am working on this page, 
http://filikaajans.com/test/index.php

when the screen resizes the footer is not displayed well,

here is the CSS for the footer:

```
#footer_1 {
    background: url("../images/bgfooter2.png") repeat-x scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    width: 100%;
}
```

I want the footer to fill the width of the screen whatever  the screen size,

I tried to fix the footer but it didn't work with me

Comment: can you explain what it is you want to happen?

Comment: There are many things wrong with your site. I personally would suggest a complete redo of the site. Things such as increasing or decreasing the width causes elements to overlap other elements.

Comment: is there a starting point to fix it?

Comment: could it because the size of the background for body element is 1600*904??

Answer (score 0):

The height on .logos pushes them down when the interior elements collapse. Take the fixed height off.